# Accessing a Google App Engine application from a Windows application using OAuth

Tags: windows, google-app-engine, oauth

We have an application built on top of the Google App Engine.  We now need to write a Windows 7 tray application that accesses services provided by our GAE application.  This implies that we need to first make an OAuth connection to our application, and we are finding it difficult to locate information about how to accomplish this.

We have already successfully used Google's [OAuth2 API .net client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2) to establish a trusted connection from our Windows application to the Google API, but this does not seem to also give us access to the Google App Engine which seems to live in a different part of the ether.

So first, I would like to ask, are we correct in our understanding that Google App Engine only supports OAuth 1.0 and does not support OAuth 2 as the rest of the Google API seems to support?

And second, (assuming the answer to the above is yes) does anyone know of any information or example code where someone has already made a successful OAuth 1.0 connection from a Windows .NET (C#) application to a Google App Engine application?  It would be of great help to us to locate such an example.

Answer (score 1):

Google App Engine supports just [Oauth 1.0](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/oauth/overview?hl=it) and it is still an experimental feature.

Having to deal with a .NET C# application I would proceed in this way:

1. Get the [DevDefined OAuth](http://code.google.com/p/devdefined-tools/wiki/OAuth) package
2. Look the [ExampleConsumerSite](https://github.com/bittercoder/DevDefined.OAuth-Examples/tree/master/src/ExampleConsumerSite) here
3. Port in C# the relative simple step explained in [Java](http://fabiouechi.blogspot.it/2011/11/using-google-oauth-java-client-to.html) or [Python](http://ikaisays.com/2011/05/26/setting-up-an-oauth-provider-on-google-app-engine/)

Comment: Those are excellent suggestions.  I was already on the path of trying your step #3.  But steps #1 and #2 are definitely additional information I wasn't aware of.  Thank you, and I'll let you know how it turns out.